# How can I redirect to the same url?

Tags: php, request, silex

I'm trying to figure out how to make redirect to the same url after processing form in silex:

```
public function someAction(Application $app) 
{
    $form = ... // building form

    if ('POST' === $app['request']->getMethod()) {
        $form->bindRequest($app['request']);

        if ($form->isValid()) 
        {
            $url = $app['url_generator']->generate(
                $app['request']->get('_route'),
                $app['request']->get('_route_params')
            );

            return $app->redirect($url);
        }
    }

    return $app['twig']->render(
       'form.html.twig', 
        array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
        )
    );
}
```

It's possible in [Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/book/forms.html#handling-form-submissions), but it's not working here. (Of course, i can always redirect to something like `$url?success`)

UPD: There's **everything correct** with $url. The point is that if you are trying to redirect to exactly **the same url**, it won't work.

Comment: `$url = $app['request']->getUri(); $app->redirect($url);` does not work?

Comment: nope.. Seems, like redirect to exactly the same url is not working at all

Comment: What does `var_dump($app['request']->getUri());` give?

Comment: It gives me back current url: `String(20) http://website/items`

Comment: And is that the URL of your form?

Comment: Can you give us a small application that produces the error so we can test and debug it?

Answer (score 2):

The Request class has a [`getRequestUri()`](https://github.com/symfony/HttpFoundation/blob/master/Request.php#L904) method. You can use that like this:

```
return $app->redirect($request->getRequestUri());
```

Comment: nope. everything, that is equal to current url is not working

Comment: Did you add the `return` to your code? Your question does not have it.

Comment: yes, sorry, forgot about that. Actually, it works if i change redirect  url, but doesn't work with the same location

Comment: The exact same code works for me. What does your log say? What does your access log say?

Comment: I dunno, maybe it's something todo with nginx, that im using?

Comment: that's what im talking about.. it's really fine with same library in symfony

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to answer your question with another question, but *why* would you want to redirect to the same page? The logic for your route should simply display your view after processing the form.

```
public function someAction(Application $app) 
{
    $form = ... // building form

    if ('POST' === $app['request']->getMethod()) {
        $form->bindRequest($app['request']);

        if ($form->isValid()) 
        {
            $url = $app['url_generator']->generate(
                $app['request']->get('_route'),
                $app['request']->get('_route_params')
            );

            //return $app->redirect($url);
            // just remove the return here and you're all set!
        }
    }

    return $app['twig']->render(
       'form.html.twig', 
        array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: because if somebody will refresh the page, form will be sent one more time.

Comment: That's really on the user. The browser will prompt them letting them know that the form will be resubmitted along with any POST data.

Comment: I think it's better to prevent all that if you can. And I can do that in symfony2, but it doesn't work here.